# Apache Karaf 2.2.3, featuresBoot issue

Tags: apache-karaf, spring-jms

Karaf 2.2.3 recently released and finally has a pre-bundled spring-jms feature. In order to make life easy I added it to the featuresBoot config property with the other defaults:

`featuresBoot=config,ssh,management,spring-jms`

However, when I start Karaf it behaves uncontrollably. Sometimes it will install on boot and other times it doesn't. When it doesn't auto-install I attempt to add it via the command line:

`features:install spring-jms`

And even that behaves wildly. See below:

```
karaf@root> features:install spring-jms
Error executing command: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

karaf@root> features:install spring-jms
Error executing command: invalid entry size (expected 3293 but got 16823 bytes)

karaf@root> features:install spring-jms
Error executing command: Manifest not present in the first entry of the zip mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aopalliance/1.0_5

karaf@root> features:install spring-jms
Refreshing bundles org.springframework.context.support (50)
Error executing command: Could not start bundle mvn:org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client/7.4.5.v20110725 in feature(s) jetty-7.4.5.v20110725: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.eclipse.jetty.client [83]: Unable to resolve 83.0: missing requirement [83.0] package; (&(package=org.eclipse.jetty.http)(version>=7.4.0)(!(version>=8.0.0)))

karaf@root> features:install spring-jms
Refreshing bundles org.springframework.context.support (50)
```

Those are back-to-back executions of the install command. The last execution works.

Anyone else see this behavior? Or know how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tony,

First, make sure that you are using the correct version Java, I use jdk 1.6_24. When using this, with no other bundles installed (a fresh installation), it installs properly.  If I were you I would:
1) try installing a fresh instance of Karaf,
2) copy your maven repository to a new location, and 
3) run Karaf in a fresh installation,
4) install spring-jms again.

If that doesn't work, reply to this and let me know your environment, along with all of the exceptions generated in your karaf log file.

Comment: So I wiped my installation. From a stock Karaf (jdk1.6.0_26), spring-jms installs without any stack traces. So I shutdown and added spring-jms to the featuresBoot and got no stack traces. Currently, it "seems" to be working. I couldn't imagine that it somehow got corrupted, because that would imply the jars in my maven repo are also corrupted?

Comment: Thats absolutely possible. As a karaf contributor, I get the chance to vote on every release of Karaf, which requires compiling it starting it, and then using it.  In this process, I've found that sometimes corrupt files to get into my repository, and that starting from a fresh repository alleviates that problem. Also, it may not be that the .jars got corrupted, there are a number of places where, in the installation of .jars into your repository that the process could be halted, resulting in the appearance of a corrupted .jar file when it may actually be an incomplete pom or something else.

Comment: I left my repository as is. I've re-added my settings. I've run into plenty of problems before shutting down and rebooting Karaf too quickly. So, perhaps I need to be less harsh when I'm testing things.

Comment: If your Karaf instance seems corrupt you can run recent versions with the clean option the clear any state accumulated.   ./bin/karaf clean

Comment: I always run with the clean option. This doesn't seem to help. I'm once again in the state with spring-jms not properly installing.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance are you using a customized org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg? I am, and it has caused a huge boot-time race condition problem that led to features sporadically failing to load.

Take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-910 "Race between FeatureService and ConfigAdmin for resolving mvn: URLs?"